# Using Fedora 19 to burn .iso-image to external HDD

Tags: fedora, iso, burning

Seeing as several google-searches have failed me, I am having a hard time completing this task. I am currently running Fedora 19 on my laptop, and I wish to burn a .iso-image to an external HDD. Seeing as Brasero and several other programs that are seemingly made for this purpose are not recognizing said HDD (looks like they only accept flashdrives?) I am unable to find any way to burn it.

The disk is formatted to NTFS. I have also tried with FAT.

I am relatively new to Linux and would highly appreciate being spoonfed if anyone would find the time to do so.

Some clarification might be needed: I already have Fedora 19 installed. I wish to install Windows XP as well. I have a 500 GB HDD I'd like to install it on. I have tried the following:

- Programs like Brassero etc. Does not recognize the HDD.
- Running the .iso in a VM, but the external HDD is not an alternative as an installation disc.
- Using dd. This did work somewhat, seeing as the disc was renamed to "WINDOWS XP HOME EDITION" blablabla, but when booting it I simply got the message "unable to load operating system." After this, I formatted the disc again.

I have successfully installed XP on a VM, so there is nothing wrong with the .iso itself.

Please note that my objective is to have XP on the external HDD, if this can be achieved by other means, those answers are naturally accepted.

Comment: You don't really burn things to hard disks. Look at mounting the ISO and copying the contents or using `dd` to write the raw disk contents to a partition.  If your target partition is formatted you most likely want the mount and copy option.

Comment: This sounds like maybe you're trying to create an install medium? In that case, [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) could be what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes, as the edit suggests, I am trying to install XP. UNetbootin does not recognize the disc.

Answer (score 1):

The nature of this question has changed since I answered it (and now seems a bit offtopic to UL), but here is a second take on it.

If you want XP on the external hard drive you could install in a VM using the raw disk partition as the backing storage (rather than a sparse file).  Don't install the guest additions or other things and you can probably boot from the disk using grub (but may have to re-activate from changing hardware)

Another method is going to be installing XP on any computer, and then cloning the install to the external hard drive (I don't think a normal XP install is going to let you install directly to the external disk).

"Burning" or copying the contents of an XP install CD to a drive will not install XP and doesn't sound like it will further your goal.

Comment: The terminal claims that the .iso is already mounted.

Comment: Thank you for the new response. The only alternative mentioned here that seems doable for me is installing on a VM and then doing whatever you suggested. I am not experienced enough to fully understand what you mean, but isn't it possible to clone the install from the VM to the external disc, and then boot it?

Answer (score 0):

You typically do not "burn" .iso files to HDD's, only to optical media, hence the term "burn", as in "burning into the ROM" media.

Also the .iso files you download from the Fedora project are meant to be written to either a removable USB flash drive or "burned" to a DVD/CD ROM. Once they've been written to this medium, they can be used as a source drive for doing installations to actual HDD's.

This last step should not be overlooked. There is decision logic that needs to be executed in the form of dialogs presented to the user or program logic that integrogates a system's hardware make-up and then installs the appropriate software for that particular system's hardware.

You cannot simply dump the .iso onto a HDD and call it a Fedora installation.

Comment: I already have Fedora installed and working. I wish to install dualboot Windows XP.

Comment: @AndrewThompson - I always install Windows XP 1st, and Fedora 2nd.

Comment: @AndrewThompson - you might want to rework your Q then, what you're up to is not getting through to us in its current form 8-)

Comment: Alright, I'll do that.